# React Native app sides being cut off in Android

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have absolutely no idea what might be causing this. It's only happening on the newest version we just released of the app, so it might be a little bit easier to track down the culprit, but still I can't figure out what's going on and no google search managed to helped me out.

I'm pasting a [print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn7i8.jpg) of what's going on. As stated before I have no idea what can be causing this, so **I don't know what code to paste here**, but I'll provide code as you ask for. Thanks in advance!

[image: Print screen of the pages being cut off]

Comment: Just noticed that modals are not being cut

Comment: posting your code would help members understand what's going on, otherwise there's a lot of guesswork.

Comment: As I mentioned, there's a lot of code, and since this is happening on all pages, and I can't have any idea of what's causing it, I don't know what piece of code to post. I'm here to paste it as soon as anyone asks for it. Trying to find possible culpripts will lead to me pasting some code, so it kind is a bit of guesswork to start with... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem:

In an attempt to center the icon of the loading splash screen, I had `<bitmap android:gravity="center" ... />` in app/src/main/res/drawable/background_splash.xml, which is the file I use to configure the splash/launch screen.

And this is where the problem resides. For whatever reason I have no knowledge of, `android:gravity="center"` sets the size of the screen to whatever resolution of the image used as the background splash has.

## Solution:

Simply changing `android:gravity="center"` to `android:gravity="fill"` does it. Downside is it scales the background splash image to the full resolution of the device viewport, thus distorcing the image, so you gotta find another way to go about your splash, but that isn't that big of a deal.